# how to enlarge image until top of page making content wrap in beamer?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, wrap

my companies CI wants a picture (PNG) on the right side of certain but not all frames (TOC / Section starter)

My problem is that I don't get the picture to reach until the top of the frame, there is always some empty space above. I already found some answeres about stratching an image, but my Picture is **not** some kind of background.

the desired output is:

### [image: the desired output]

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,hyperref={unicode},t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headerline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode\hbox to \paperwidth{%
    \color{white}{\hfill some footer text%
        \hfill \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber}
        \hspace{2em}%
    }%
  \vskip1.5ex%
}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \fill[gray,thin] (0.0,0.0) rectangle (\paperwidth,3ex);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\subsection{Test Test}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.493\textwidth}
    \hbox to .35\paperwidth{
        \vbox to \paperheight{
            %% this will be replaced by a includegraphics:
            \tikz \draw [red,anchor=south east,ultra thick] (0,0) rectangle (.462\textwidth,-.935\textheight);
            %% how to enlagre until top of page? 
        }
    }
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{frame}[t]{how to enlarge image until top of page making content wrap?}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item content must wrap before image (works for title already)
        \item image must end with top and right edge of page
        \item image must connect to gray bar drawn in background\\
              may ''slip'' behind it but must not overlap amd have no gap between
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.493\textwidth}
    \hbox to .35\paperwidth{
        \vbox to \paperheight{
            %% this will be replaced by a includegraphics:
            \tikz \draw [red,anchor=south east,ultra thick] (0,0) rectangle (.462\textwidth,-.935\textheight);
            %% how to enlagre until top of page? 
        }
    }
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{frame}[t]{why does minipage move the image?}
    \begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][t]{.4\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item content must wrap before image (works for title already)
            \item image must end with top and right edge of page
            \item image must connect to gray bar drawn in background\\
                  may ''slip'' behind it but must not overlap amd have no gap between
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you can see I tried to solve the line wrapping problem with `minipage` but this bade my initial problem worse...

Here is how it currently looks like:

[image: current output with image too low]

Comment: Basically, you are trying to do everything the wrapfig manual says won't work.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks for the comment, but how do I do it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, you can put a `frame` inside a `minipage` without moving it.  It is relatively easy to place an image to the right of a minipage.

The first page demonstrates the difference between the text area and the page size, hence the creation of `\beamermargin`.  (There is probably a length already defined in `beamer`, and you are welcome to search through the source code to try and find it.)  The `\hspace{-\beamermargin}` is used to move the image all the way to the right edge of the page.

It should be noted that `\tikz` and `\includegraphics` often become slightly larger than expected, so in general one might want to use `.99\textheight` to avoid creating blank pages.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,hyperref={unicode},t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headerline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode\hbox to \paperwidth{%
    \color{white}{\hfill some footer text%
        \hfill \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber}
        \hspace{2em}%
    }%
  \vskip1.5ex%
}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \fill[gray,thin] (0.0,0.0) rectangle (\paperwidth,3ex);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newlength{\beamermargin}
\setlength{\beamermargin}{\dimexpr 0.5\paperwidth-0.5\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}

\begin{minipage}[b][\textheight][t]{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{frame}[t]{how to enlarge image until top of page making content wrap?}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item content must wrap before image (works for title already)
        \item image must end with top and right edge of page
        \item image must connect to gray bar drawn in background\\
              may ''slip'' behind it but must not overlap amd have no gap between
    \end{itemize}
    \vfill
    \rule{\textwidth}{10pt}
  \end{frame}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\rule{.35\paperwidth}{\textheight}%
\hspace{-\beamermargin}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This solution overlays the image on the page.  It takes two runs to get the positioning right.  The environment `wraptext` is similar to `minipage` but allows page breaking.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,hyperref={unicode},t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headerline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode\hbox to \paperwidth{%
    \color{white}{\hfill some footer text%
        \hfill \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber}
        \hspace{2em}%
    }%
  \vskip1.5ex%
}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \fill[gray,thin] (0.0,0.0) rectangle (\paperwidth,3ex);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newenvironment{wraptext}[1][.35\paperwidth]% #1 is width of image (optional)
{\addtolength{\textwidth}{-#1}\hsize=\textwidth}{}

\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[below left,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east)
{\includegraphics[width=.35\paperwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image}};}% no gap
\begin{wraptext}
\lipsum[1]
\end{wraptext}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: This is great, thanks! but when I change `\rule{.35\paperwidth}{\textheight}` with `\includegraphics[width=.35\paperwidth,\textheight]{thePng}` I get `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
\endcsname
l.45 ...=.35\paperwidth,\textheight]{`

Comment: when I replace the `itemize` with `\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]` the "image surrogate" moves to an "intermediate" frame: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpHWK.png

Comment: \includegraphics[width=.35\paperwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image}% worked fine.  Does the \tableofcontents fit on one page, as this is the downside of using a minipage.

Comment: Unfortunately the *wraptext* approach does not work either. when I replace the blind text with the toc i get a compile error: `! Undefined control sequence.
\beamerx@\beamer@noargsonslide ...beamer@endpause
\alt #1{\beamer@spacingcov...
l.57 \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]` when I sourround it with a new frame it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dGIT.png (image on a separate frame animation phase)

Comment: Finally got it! :oD Your first suggestion did it. I had a type in here: _\includegraphics[width=.35\paperwidth, **height=** \textheight]_ the bold part was missing.

Comment: I still have a (hopefully small) problem: the approach inserts an empty frame before and  ruins the frame numbering: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FgTz.png should I open a new question so that I can post the current source?

Comment: An empty page, especially the first page, can be caused by the page being just slightly too large.